# RabbitMQ Shovel Error NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to create a shovel from my old (RabbitMQ Server 3.6.1) broker to my new (RabbitMQ 3.6.6) broker and I keep getting this error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Nov-2016::18:42:45 ===
** Generic server <0.23222.460> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',init}
** When Server state == {state,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                            {<<"/myvhost">>,<<"Test">>},
                            dynamic,
                            {shovel,
                                {endpoint,
                                    ["amqp://user:password@localhost:5672/myvhost"],
                                    #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.4.22841904>},
                                {endpoint,
                                    ["amqp://user:password0@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5672/myvhost"],
                                    #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.5.22841904>},
                                1000,no_ack,
                                #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.6.22841904>,
                                #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.7.22841904>,
                                <<"queue_name">>,
                                1,'queue-length'},
                            undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined}
** Reason for termination ==
** {{badmatch,{error,not_allowed}},
    [{rabbit_shovel_worker,make_conn_and_chan,1,
                           [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,236}]},
     {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2,
                           [{file,"src/rabbit_shovel_worker.erl"},{line,62}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1049}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
```

The log lines above are happening on the source server and nothing is being shown on the logs in the destination server.

I have verified (using e.g. telnet) and the destination server:port is reachable and the user and password being used are correct.

I have created the shovel using destination and source queue names and not exchanges. The queue and vhost already exist in the destination server.

Does anyone have any ideas about this issue or have run into it in the past? This is the first time I am working with shovel thus I may be missing a basic step.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: A few things to check when debugging your shovel setup: 1. The users for the source and destination brokers have permissions necessary to the vhosts and objects in them. 2. The vhost/queues/exchanges in both the source and destination exist (or you are declaring those definitions): [https://github.com/rabbitinaction/sourcecode/blob/master/configs/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config.shovel](https://github.com/rabbitinaction/sourcecode/blob/master/configs/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config.shovel)